# Посадка на Bitrix owl слайдера. Создание инфоблока

Tags: php, html, css, битрикс, owl-carousel

Создал тип инфоблока - **Слайдер** на битриксе и сам инфоблок - слайдер, который включает в себя фоновое изображение слайда (картинка анонса инфоблока слайдер), имя слайда, фотографию автора слайда (строковому свойству **PictureUrl** анонса задал путь к фотографии автора слайда), имя автора (задал строковому свойству **Author** анонса), дату создания слайда (задал свойству типа дата **DateTime** анонса ). (действовал согласно [Инструкции](https://it-blog.ru/bitrix/sozdanie-komponenty-1s-bitriks-na-primere-slajdera/)) Должно получиться как на скриншоте

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Шаблон взят с сайта [w3layouts](https://w3layouts.com/template/publication-a-corporate-blogging-category-website-template/).

Есть код из этого шаблона

```html
<!-- main-slider -->

<section class="w3l-main-slider position-relative" id="home">
  <div class="companies20-content">
    <div class="owl-one owl-carousel owl-theme">
      <div class="item">
        <li>
          <div class="slider-info banner-view bg bg2">
            <div class="banner-info">
              <div class="container">
                <div class="banner-info-bg text-center">
                  <a href="#blog-single.html" class="blog_post_title">How to Make Cappuccino without a Machine</a>
                  <ul class="author-date mb-4 d-flex align-items-center mt-4 justify-content-center">
                    <li class="circle avatar"><img src="<?=SITE_TEMPLATE_PATH ?>/assets/images/author1.jpg" alt=""></li>
                    <li>by <a href="#author.html">John Michele</a></li>
                    <li><span class="fa fa-clock-o" aria-hidden="true"></span> Mar 16, 2020</li>
                  </ul>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </li>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <li>
          <div class="slider-info  banner-view banner-top1 bg bg2">
            <div class="banner-info">
              <div class="container">
                <div class="banner-info-bg text-center">
                  <a href="#blog-single.html" class="blog_post_title">Create a Stunning Website!</a>
                  <ul class="author-date mb-4 d-flex align-items-center mt-4 justify-content-center">
                    <li class="circle avatar"><img src="<?=SITE_TEMPLATE_PATH ?>/assets/images/author2.jpg" alt=""></li>
                    <li>by <a href="#author.html">Daniel Roberto</a></li>
                    <li><span class="fa fa-clock-o" aria-hidden="true"></span> Jan 22, 2020</li>
                  </ul>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </li>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <li>
          <div class="slider-info banner-view banner-top2 bg bg2">
            <div class="banner-info">
              <div class="container">
                <div class="banner-info-bg text-center">
                  <a href="#blog-single.html" class="blog_post_title">See yourself in a New Light.</a>
                  <ul class="author-date mb-4 d-flex align-items-center mt-4 justify-content-center">
                    <li class="circle avatar"><img src="<?=SITE_TEMPLATE_PATH ?>/assets/images/author3.jpg" alt=""></li>
                    <li>by <a href="#author.html">Emma Stone</a></li>
                    <li><span class="fa fa-clock-o" aria-hidden="true"></span> Aug 14, 2020</li>
                  </ul>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </li>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</section>
```

Подскажите как этот код можно посадить на bitrix?

Если действовать согласно [Инструкции](https://it-blog.ru/bitrix/sozdanie-komponenty-1s-bitriks-na-primere-slajdera/), то код шаблона компонента Список новостей надо переделать из файла `C:\OpenServer\domains\bxsite3.ru\local\templates\blog\components\bitrix\news.list\myowlslider\template.php`

```html
<?if(!defined("B_PROLOG_INCLUDED") || B_PROLOG_INCLUDED!==true)die();
/** @var array $arParams */
/** @var array $arResult */
/** @global CMain $APPLICATION */
/** @global CUser $USER */
/** @global CDatabase $DB */
/** @var CBitrixComponentTemplate $this */
/** @var string $templateName */
/** @var string $templateFile */
/** @var string $templateFolder */
/** @var string $componentPath */
/** @var CBitrixComponent $component */
$this->setFrameMode(true);
?>
  <div class="news-list">
    <?if($arParams["DISPLAY_TOP_PAGER"]):?>
      <?=$arResult["NAV_STRING"]?><br />
        <?endif;?>
          <?foreach($arResult["ITEMS"] as $arItem):?>
            <?
    $this->AddEditAction($arItem['ID'], $arItem['EDIT_LINK'], CIBlock::GetArrayByID($arItem["IBLOCK_ID"], "ELEMENT_EDIT"));
    $this->AddDeleteAction($arItem['ID'], $arItem['DELETE_LINK'], CIBlock::GetArrayByID($arItem["IBLOCK_ID"], "ELEMENT_DELETE"), array("CONFIRM" => GetMessage('CT_BNL_ELEMENT_DELETE_CONFIRM')));
    ?>
              <?echo '<pre>', var_dump($arItem) ,'</pre>';?>
                <div class="news-item" id="<?=$this->GetEditAreaId($arItem['ID']);?>">
                  <?if($arParams["DISPLAY_PICTURE"]!="N" && is_array($arItem["PREVIEW_PICTURE"])):?>
                    <?if(!$arParams["HIDE_LINK_WHEN_NO_DETAIL"] || ($arItem["DETAIL_TEXT"] && $arResult["USER_HAVE_ACCESS"])):?>
                      <a href="<?=$arItem[" DETAIL_PAGE_URL "]?>"><img
                        class="preview_picture"
                        border="0"
                        src="<?=$arItem["PREVIEW_PICTURE"]["SRC"]?>"
                        width="<?=$arItem["PREVIEW_PICTURE"]["WIDTH"]?>"
                        height="<?=$arItem["PREVIEW_PICTURE"]["HEIGHT"]?>"
                        alt="<?=$arItem["PREVIEW_PICTURE"]["ALT"]?>"
                        title="<?=$arItem["PREVIEW_PICTURE"]["TITLE"]?>"
                        style="float:left"
                        /></a>
                      <?else:?>
                        <img class="preview_picture" border="0" src="<?=$arItem[" PREVIEW_PICTURE "]["SRC "]?>" width="<?=$arItem[" PREVIEW_PICTURE "]["WIDTH "]?>" height="<?=$arItem[" PREVIEW_PICTURE "]["HEIGHT "]?>" alt="<?=$arItem[" PREVIEW_PICTURE "]["ALT "]?>" title="<?=$arItem["
                          PREVIEW_PICTURE "]["TITLE "]?>" style="float:left" />
                        <?endif;?>
                          <?endif?>
                            <?if($arParams["DISPLAY_DATE"]!="N" && $arItem["DISPLAY_ACTIVE_FROM"]):?>
                              <span class="news-date-time"><?echo $arItem["DISPLAY_ACTIVE_FROM"]?></span>
                              <?endif?>
                                <?if($arParams["DISPLAY_NAME"]!="N" && $arItem["NAME"]):?>
                                  <?if(!$arParams["HIDE_LINK_WHEN_NO_DETAIL"] || ($arItem["DETAIL_TEXT"] && $arResult["USER_HAVE_ACCESS"])):?>
                                    <a href="<?echo $arItem[" DETAIL_PAGE_URL "]?>"><b><?echo $arItem["NAME"]?></b></a><br />
                                    <?else:?>
                                      <b><?echo $arItem["NAME"]?></b><br />
                                      <?endif;?>
                                        <?endif;?>
                                          <?if($arParams["DISPLAY_PREVIEW_TEXT"]!="N" && $arItem["PREVIEW_TEXT"]):?>
                                            <?echo $arItem["PREVIEW_TEXT"];?>
                                              <?endif;?>
                                                <?if($arParams["DISPLAY_PICTURE"]!="N" && is_array($arItem["PREVIEW_PICTURE"])):?>
                                                  <div style="clear:both"></div>
                                                  <?endif?>
                                                    <?foreach($arItem["FIELDS"] as $code=>$value):?>
                                                      <small>
            <?=GetMessage("IBLOCK_FIELD_".$code)?>:&nbsp;<?=$value;?>
            </small><br />
                                                      <?endforeach;?>
                                                        <?foreach($arItem["DISPLAY_PROPERTIES"] as $pid=>$arProperty):?>
                                                          <small>
            <?=$arProperty["NAME"]?>:&nbsp;
            <?if(is_array($arProperty["DISPLAY_VALUE"])):?>
                <?=implode("&nbsp;/&nbsp;", $arProperty["DISPLAY_VALUE"]);?>
            <?else:?>
                <?=$arProperty["DISPLAY_VALUE"];?>
            <?endif?>
            </small><br />
                                                          <?endforeach;?>
                </div>
                <?endforeach;?>
                  <?if($arParams["DISPLAY_BOTTOM_PAGER"]):?>
                    <br />
                    <?=$arResult["NAV_STRING"]?>
                      <?endif;?>
  </div>
```

в файл

```html
<?if(!defined("B_PROLOG_INCLUDED") || B_PROLOG_INCLUDED!==true)die();?>
  <div class="owl-carousel">
    <?foreach($arResult["ITEMS"] as $arItem):?>
      <?
     $this->AddEditAction($arItem['ID'], $arItem['EDIT_LINK'], CIBlock::GetArrayByID($arItem["IBLOCK_ID"], "ELEMENT_EDIT"));
     $this->AddDeleteAction($arItem['ID'], $arItem['DELETE_LINK'], CIBlock::GetArrayByID($arItem["IBLOCK_ID"], "ELEMENT_DELETE"), array("CONFIRM" =>GetMessage('CT_BNL_ELEMENT_DELETE_CONFIRM')));
    ?>
        <div id="<?=$this->GetEditAreaId($arItem['ID']);?>">
          <img src="<?=$arItem[" PREVIEW_PICTURE "]["SRC "]?>" />
        </div>
        <?endforeach;?>
  </div>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $(".owl-carousel").owlCarousel({
        items: 1,
      })
    });
  </script>
```

1. Вопрос состоит в том как именовать классы div-ов в конечном файле template.php (а именно необходимо сопоставить эти классы с классами исходного шаблона сайта). А именно как соотнести класс `news-list` с классом `owl-one owl-carousel owl-theme`  и т.п.? (эти классы описаны в файле `C:\OpenServer\domains\bxsite3.ru\local\templates\blog\assets\css\style-starter.css`)
2. Как получить значения свойств **Author**, **DateTime** и **PictureUrl** инфоблока?
3. Каким образом можно повесить класс `banner-top№` на все слайды, кроме первого?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Не надо соотносить классы div-ов. Надо писать новые. У вас в шаблоне слайдера итемы обёрнуты в три тега, значит и в шаблоне компонента оберните цикл по итемам в эти три тега.

```
<?if(!defined("B_PROLOG_INCLUDED") || B_PROLOG_INCLUDED!==true)die();?>
  <section class="w3l-main-slider position-relative" id="home">
    <div class="companies20-content">
      <div class="owl-one owl-carousel owl-theme">
        <?foreach($arResult["ITEMS"] as $arItem):?>
          <?
            $this->AddEditAction($arItem['ID'], $arItem['EDIT_LINK'], CIBlock::GetArrayByID($arItem["IBLOCK_ID"], "ELEMENT_EDIT"));
            $this->AddDeleteAction($arItem['ID'], $arItem['DELETE_LINK'], CIBlock::GetArrayByID($arItem["IBLOCK_ID"], "ELEMENT_DELETE"), array("CONFIRM" =>GetMessage('CT_BNL_ELEMENT_DELETE_CONFIRM')));
          ?>
          <div id="<?=$this->GetEditAreaId($arItem['ID']);?>">
            <img src="<?=$arItem[" PREVIEW_PICTURE "]["SRC "]?>" />
          </div>
        <?endforeach;?>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
<?endif;?>
```

То же касается и итемов внутри цикла.

2. Не нужно помещать скрипт в шаблон. Поместите его в файл script.js в папке шаблона.

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $(".owl-carousel").owlCarousel({
        items: 1,
      })
    });
```

3. Если речь о пользовательских значениях, то их можно получить из `$arItem['PROPERTIES]['AUTHOR']['VALUE']`. Чтобы пользовательские значения подцепились, необходимо указать в параметрах вызова компонента хотя бы одно из них.

Comment: см. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1372741/%d0%92%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b4-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d1%80%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%ba-%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%bd%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b2-%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%84%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b2-%d0%b2-%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%b4%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5. Может все таки дело в классах (в css)?